# How to solve the FunctionError and MapError

Tags: python, prettytable

Python 3.6 pycharm

```
import prettytable as pt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a=np.random.randn(30,2)
b=a.round(2)
df=pd.DataFrame(b)
df.columns=['data1','data2']
tb = pt.PrettyTable()

def func1(columns):
    def func2(column):
        return tb.add_column(column,df[column])
    return map(func2,columns)

column1=['data1','data2']
print(column1)
print(func1(column1))
```

I want to get the results are:

```
tb.add_column('data1',df['data1'])
tb.add_column('data2',df['data2'])
```

As a matter of fact，the results are:

```
<map object at 0x000001E527357828>
```

I am trying find the answer in Stack Overflow for a long time, some answer tell me can use `list(func1(column1))`, but the result is `[None, None]`.

Comment: Thank you for your advice，my English is poor，but I will try my best to learn about  the sections named How to Ask. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the tutorial at https://ptable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html, `PrettyTable.add_column` modifies the `PrettyTable` in-place. Such functions generally return `None`, not the modified object.

You're also overcomplicating the problem by trying to use `map` and a fancy wrapper function. The below code is much simpler, but produces the desired result.

```
import prettytable as pt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

column_names = ['data1', 'data2']

a = np.random.randn(30, 2)
b = a.round(2)
df = pd.DataFrame(b)
df.columns = column_names
tb = pt.PrettyTable()

for col in column_names:
    tb.add_column(col, df[col])

print(tb)
```

---

If you're still interesting in learning about the thing that `map` returns, I suggest reading about [iterables](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) and [iterators](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator). `map` returns an iterator over the results of calling the function, and does not actually do any work until you iterate over it.

Comment: First, thank you  very much, the results  are satisfy my needs. I learned the use of wrapper function  on the day before yesterday, and it can solve the complicated problems effectively.I use wrapper function to  return the results, I think  in these process need not the PrettyTable return results.

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear if you're asking another question. If you are, please submit a new question with the new problem. If this answer was helpful, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: import prettytable as pt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a=np.random.randn(30,2)
b=a.round(2)

df=pd.DataFrame(b)
df.columns=['data1','data2']
df.index=pd.date_range('2017-1-1',periods=len(b),freq='M')
tb = pt.PrettyTable()

print(df.index,type(df.index))
print(df.head(),type(df))
print(df.columns.values)

tb.add_column('dates',df.index)
for col in df.columns.values:
    tb.add_column(col, df[col])
print(tb)

Comment: I can not put the code add  in the comment with the correct format.
I search the answer  from Google https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74784/how-do-i-add-code-while-writing-comments
but it doesn't work can you help me.

Comment: As I mentioned before, if you have another question you should submit a new, separate question with your new code example. You cannot and should not put large code samples in comments.